# How to auto- fit the Kendo UI Grid last column after resizing it?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I am re-sizing Kendo Grid, The Last Column of grid is not fitting properly to the Grid after leaving the Re-sizing. The Last column should Automatically fit properly to the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the scrollable property as false,
Please find the fiddle [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/APequ/2)